# Sending email from VB.net Windows Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, email

I have written the following code to send an email from a VB.net windows Form. 
Here is my code

```
Try
        Dim message As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        Dim fromMailAddress As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress
        Dim toMailAddress As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress

        fromMailAddress = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("fromEmailID@live.com")
        toMailAddress = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("toEMailID@gmail.com")

        message = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        message.From = toMailAddress
        message.To.Add(fromMailAddress)
        message.Subject = "TestFromVB"
        message.Body = "Test Message"

        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False 
        smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailid@gmail.com", "password")
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

        smtp.Send(message)

        MessageBox.Show("sent...") 

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.ToString())
    End Try
```

Whenever i click on a button **send**, it should send email to the address specified. Bu this code is giving some error saying **Unable to connect to remote machine....**

Here is the screenshot of exception 
[image]

Can anybody please help me to fix this issue. or Please suggest if you have any working sample.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use a different port number either `587` or `465`

As per [this GMail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) document.

> - **Incoming Mail (POP3) Server - requires SSL:** `pop.gmail.com`
>
>   - Use SSL: `Yes`
>   - Port: `995`
> - **Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS or SSL:**
>     `smtp.gmail.com`
>
>   - Use Authentication: `Yes`
>   - Port for TLS/STARTTLS: `587`
>   - Port for SSL: `465`
>   - Account Name: `your full email address (including @gmail.com or
>       @your_domain.com)`
>   - Email Address:`your email address (username@gmail.com or
>       username@your_domain.com)`
>   - Password: `your Gmail password`

Answer (score 0):

GMail uses port 587 for the smtp server. See this code sample:

http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/10/how-to-send-email-via-gmail-smtp-in.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles on this question, besides the port needing to be correct as the other answers pointed out, many times Google will not authenticate from a Vb.net program without changing the setting in your google account to allow less secure connections. [link to google settings](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)